# how get yesterday and tomorrow datetime in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a code:

```
int MonthNow = System.DateTime.Now.Month;
int YearNow = System.DateTime.Now.Year;
int DayNow = System.DateTime.Now.Day;
```

How can I get yesterday and tomorrow day, month and year in C#?

Of course, I can just write:

```
DayTommorow = DayNow +1;
```

but it may happen that tomorrow is other month or year. Are there in C# built-in tools to find out yesterday and today?

Comment: The problem with `DayNow + 1` or `- 1` is if it is the first of last day of the month this wont work. DateTime.Now.Day is just an integer representation of the current day.

Answer (score 170, accepted):

You can find this info right in the [API reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx).

```
var today = DateTime.Today;
var tomorrow = today.AddDays(1);
var yesterday = today.AddDays(-1);
```

Comment: Please post if possible the relevant part of the linked website instead of *only* linking to the website

Comment: JMax, 
Sure. The link is for DateTime.AddDays Method, which allows adding/subtracting days.  This is easier to use in the context of the question, compared to the more generic DateTime.Add method.

Comment: ...and that could be the detailed part of your answer :).

Comment: How about 30th and 31th day ? It returns me 01/01/0001

Answer (score 191):

```
DateTime tomorrow = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
DateTime yesterday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
```

Comment: This answer proves how naming is important.

Answer (score 20):

You should do it this way, if you want to get yesterday and tomorrow at 00:00:00 time:

```
DateTime yesterday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
DateTime tomorrow = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1); // Output example: 6. 02. 2016 00:00:00
```

Just bare in mind that if you do it this way:

```
DateTime yesterday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
DateTime tomorrow = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1); // Output example: 6. 02. 2016 18:09:23
```

then you will get the current time minus one day, and not yesterday at 00:00:00 time.

Answer (score 19):

Today :

`DateTime.Today`

Tomorrow :

```
DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)
```

Yesterday :

```
DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1)
```

Answer (score 18):

You want `DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)`.

Answer (score 15):

Use `DateTime.AddDays()` ([MSDN Documentation DateTime.AddDays Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx)).

```
DateTime tomorrow = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
DateTime yesterday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
```

Comment: Your yesterday is "24 hours ago". Use DateTime.Today to undicate a Day in a std way.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to use "DateTime" to manipulate dates; only use integers and strings when you need a "final result" from the date.

For example (pseudo code):

1. Get "DateTime tomorrow = Now + 1"
2. Determine date, day of week, day of month - whatever you want - of the resulting date.

Answer (score 2):

To get "local" yesterday in UTC.

```
  var now = DateTime.Now;
  var yesterday = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddDays(-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Beware of adding an unwanted timezone to your results, especially if the date is going to be sent out via a Web API. Use UtcNow instead, to make it timezone-less.