# C# DateTime.Now to find yesterday

Tags: c#

Currently I am making the Query to find out to get the data from SQL server.

```
SELECT * FROM ExcelOutput WHERE ADateTime >= '2014-12-03 07:00:00' AND ADateTime < '2014-12-04 12:00:00'
```

I need to create one method to get two Date object as input. The second one will be the DateTime.Now() as the input data and the first ADateTime will be the Yesterday one, how I can write the command as Yesterday? DateTime.Now .... somethings to minus one day.

Edited

What I want is

function(Today 7 a.m., Yesterday 7 a.m.)
{

}

in C#.

Then I can connect with that SQL to retrieve the data.

**This is the Correct Answer.**

Try this snippet,

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Now.Date;
today = today.AddHours(7);
DateTime yesterday = today.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromHours(24));


SELECT * FROM ExcelOutput WHERE ADateTime >= 'yesterday' AND ADateTime < 'today'
```

Credit to: [Manu Nair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4310461/manu-nair)

Comment: WHy do you need c# for this?

Comment: Because I need to make a function to retrieve the data from the database. In that function, I need two Dates as Input to retrieve the data. Let say

function(Date1, Date2)
{
// The Date 2 is the Yesterday Date, and I need to program the specific time. 
}

Comment: possible duplicate of [how get yesterday and tomorrow datetime in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203900/how-get-yesterday-and-tomorrow-datetime-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Not only the date, time also needs to be specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this snippet,

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Now.Date;
today = today.AddHours(7);
DateTime yesterday = today.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromHours(24));


SELECT * FROM ExcelOutput WHERE ADateTime >= 'yesterday' AND ADateTime < 'today'
```

Comment: Ok, 24 hours means -24 hours, then how about if I want to set up as

function(Today 7 a.m., Yesterday 7 a.m.)

Comment: you will get the exact yesterday date based on datetime.now value

Comment: you meant you want to do change in Current Date time based on your time, if you wanna go for 7 am you want to get yesterday date with 7 am ????

Comment: What I meant was

From my system date and time

function(Today 7 a.m., Yesterday 7 a.m.)
{

}

Comment: you will get it from above code, I edited based your expected result

Comment: Yes, your answer is the one I am finding for :)

Answer (score 1):

How to get the specific time of today (and yesterday):

```
var today = DateTime.Now.Date;
var todayAtSeven = DateTime.Now.Date.Add(TimeSpan.FromHours(7));
var yesterdayAtSeven = today.AddDays(-1).Add(TimeSpan.FromHours(7));
```

Comment: So TimeSpan starts to calculate from 00:00:00?

Comment: TimeSpan is an _amount_ of time. It doesn't have a start or an end.

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract one day from `DateTime.Now` by

```
DateTime yest = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
```

You can also do this to any `DateTime` object.
If you want to subtract one day from your custom date, create an object of `DateTime` by

example

```
DateTime myVar = new DateTime(2014, 6, 14, 6, 32, 0);
myVar.AddDays(-1);
```

If you want to create a specific time,

```
DateTime reqTime = new DateTime(yest.Year,yest.Month,yest.Day,myCustomhour,myCustomminute,myCustomsecond);
```

Comment: How I can get the specific Date and Time to use as Input field?

function(Date and Specific Time, Date and Specific Time)

Comment: use `myCustomhour` here to have your custom hour and so on

Answer (score 0):

I think this is possible to do with `DateTime.Now.AddDays`:

```
DateTime tomorrow = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1); //tomorow
DateTime yesterday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1); //yesterday
```

Comment: I want to insert the specific time, how to do it? Date is okay now. But I want the specific time.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday at 13:00:

```
var yesterday = DataTime.Today.AddDays(-1).AddHours(13);
```

Today gives date only.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Correct Answer.

Try this snippet,

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Now.Date;
today = today.AddHours(7);
DateTime yesterday = today.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromHours(24));


SELECT * FROM ExcelOutput WHERE ADateTime >= 'yesterday' AND ADateTime < 'today'
```

Credit to: [Manu Nair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4310461/manu-nair)